# Heroku and wicked-pdf --- libwkhtmltox.so.0 No such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I have installed wicked_pdf locally to my Rails app and it is generating pdfs.

When I push it to Heroku and try to generate a pdf, I get:

> Command Error: /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libwkhtmltox.so.0: cannot open shared object file: no such
>   file or directory

I am running Arch. wkhtmltopdf was installed using pacman and generated entries in the /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf and /usr/lib64/libwkhtmltox.so.0

wkhtmltopdf is copied to my_rails_app/bin/wkhtmltopdf and Heroku appears to find it ok.

libwkhtmltox.so.0 has been copied to three locations and Heroku still cannot find it.

my_rails_app/bin/libwkhtmltox.so.0

my_rails_app/lib/libwkhtmltox.so.0

my_rails_app/lib64/libwkhtmltox.so.0

Where does Heroku want this file?

-- EDIT --

The test "wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf" performs as expected on my local machine (it generates a pdf file).

Using "heroku run bash" brings up a command line connected to my heroku server;
% which wkhtmltopdf
=> /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf

% which libwkhtmltox.so.0
=> /app/bin/libwkhtmltox.so.0

% wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
=> wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libwkhtmltox.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be related to Heroku's use of containers and my cut and paste efforts moving symlinks not actual files (go figure). I would thank the minion at Arch who gave me the pointer I needed, but it included comments alluding to my greatly diminished mental capacity and surprise that I could even install Arch, let alone develop on it. So I'm a little reluctant to give him credit.

As it was, with new info, my google foo found https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack After removing my previous attempts at a fix and the arch pacman download, this buildpack worked where ruby gems and Arch pacman failed.

I am now a happy idiot :-)

Answer (score 1):

wicked_pdf gem is mainly dependent[enter link description here](https://github.com/bradphelan/wkhtmltopdf-heroku) on binary 'wkhtmltopdf'

In your local machine just execute command `which wkhtmltopdf` . 
It'll show you the path where it resides.
in my case it resides at `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Next in your development application, check wicked_pdf.rb
You must have defined the :exe_path to above location. 
Your syntax must be looking something like this :

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

When you move to heroku above binary and it's path configuration won't work.

You have got two alternatives here:

1st way:   Source : [This article](https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/3778949).

Create a bin folder in your application root directory and place the binary inside it.
 Your binary will reside at : `project_root/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`

Then link to :exe_path to this location.

This might work(not tried though).

**Cons : Having binary files in project directory is not a good way. The better alternative is to place your binary in AWS or any cloud service & use the path location.**

2nd way: (I have implemented)

I avoided having this binary in heroku & was not provided any access to cloud service.
 I Used wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem
 This gem internally uses the same binary(wkhtmltopdf). 
  Check bin folder of this gem(holds the same library).

Usage:
Add following gems to Gemfile.

```
   gem 'wicked_pdf'
   gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'


  config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb
   #comment out all the :exe_path settings. 
   # our application will be using wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem
   #(which will handle the path settings)
```

Rest of the Mime configuration & require statements will still work.

It did work for me. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Those are essentially the instructions I followed. Maybe I mixed something up as it didn't work in my case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the error you getting ,let me know. some minor config you are missing out.